# Typescript call to React's useMemo requires all dependencies to be of same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a React component that has 3 props.  Their types are string, string, and MyInterface[].  If any of the props change, I want to recompute a new value.  I am trying to use useMemo:

```js
const computedValue = useMemo<ComputedValueType>(
  () => computeValue(props.string1, props.string2, props.myArray), [ 
    props.string1, 
    props.string2, 
    props.myArray
  ]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Type '(string | MyInterface[])[]' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<any>'.
  Types of property 'findIndex' are incompatible.
```

Is there a work around for this?  I am new to Typescript.  Would I have to compute my own memoization based on those three props and pass that in as the dependency?  Or at that point, just not use useMemo and do my own memoization?  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

UPDATE:
It looks like my issue is only being reported in VSCode.  Running typescript from the command-line compiles the code properly.  I updated my VS Code to use the same version of Typescript, 3.9.5, that my project uses.  I still see the error in VS Code.  Anyone know of anything I can do to resolve this?

UPDATE 2:
I am able to re-create the issue in VSCode with the following .tsx file:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function Test() {

  let a = 'abc';
  let b = 'abc';
  let c = 'abc';
  let d = 'abc';

  const computedValue = useMemo(() => d, [a, b, c]);

  return (
    <div>Hi</div>
  );
}
```

The `[a, b, c]` is underlined in red with the error:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<any>'.
  Types of property 'findIndex' are incompatible.
    Type '(predicate: (value: string, index: number, obj: string[]) => any, thisArg?: any) => number' is not assignable to type '(predicate: (value: any, index: number, obj: any, T: any, []: Iterable<any>) => any, thisArg?: an...'.
      Types of parameters 'predicate' and 'predicate' are incompatible.ts(2345)
```

Comment: can you please provide the types `ComputedValueType ` and the props?

Comment: I added code that re-creates the issue.

Comment: I tried to recreate the error with a Jetbrains IDE and TS 3.9.5 and didn't get an error, so I'm guessing the issue is indeed with your IDE. You could try a workaround via type assertion `[a, b, c] as ReadonlyArray<any>`

Comment: It goes away if I disable the VS Code plugin for JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense.